# Exporting specified layers in ArcMap using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am trying to export specific layers from an ArcMap .mxd. From the TOC below I would like to export "irrig_2, citylyr, boundlyr" as a GIF. Once this is done the script would then export "irrig_1, citylyr, boundlyr" as another GIF and so on. If possible, the script would also export a legend that corresponds to the layers being exported. I'm not sure if it's a good place to start, but I'm trying to work off the code below.

[image]

[image]

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test\irrig2.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]

GIFPath = r"E:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test"

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
        if lyr.name == "citylyr":
            lyr.visible = True
        if lyr.name == "boundlyr":
            lyr.visible = True
        if lyr.name == lyr:
            lyr.visible = True
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(mxd,GIFPath+"\\" + lyr.name + ".gif")
            lyr.visible = False
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
del mxd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through a list of your output layers so you can turn them on and off for each export.

```
import arcpy

projFolder = r"E:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"{}\irrig2.mxd".format(projFolder))
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]

GIFPath = r"E:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test"

layers = ['irrig_0','irrig_1','irrig_2'] # List of your output layers

lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df)

for layer in layers:
    layerOn = "" # When required layer is turned on this will be the layer name to output
    for lyr in lyrlist:
        lyr.visible = False
        #if lyr.name in layers and lyr.name <> layer:
        #   lyr.visible = False
        if lyr.name == "citylyr":
            lyr.visible = True
        if lyr.name == "boundlyr":
            lyr.visible = True
        if lyr.name == layer:
            lyr.visible = True
            layerOn = lyr.name
    if layerOn:
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(mxd,r"{}\{}.gif".format(GIFPath,layerOn))

del mxd
```