# How to add multiple text elements in ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, layers

I've been able to add a dynamic text element (with an element name of 'TestName') that reflects a layer name and that changes for each corresponding exported layer to a GIF. I am now trying to add a second text element (with an element name of 'TestName2') for a map title but am running into issues. Below is the code I am working with. CMD prompt produces this error:

```
C:\UserS\JameS>export5.py 
[<map layer u’Div1_Irrig_1987_2’>, <map layer u’Div1_Irrig_1987_2’>, <map layer 
u’Div1_Irrig_1956_0’>, <map layer u’citylyr’>, <map layer u’boundlyr’>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Scripts\TestScripts\export5.py”, line 42, in <module>
   elm.text : "" 
   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\7base.py", line 89, in _set
      return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
RuntimeError: TextElementObject: Error in setting text

C:\Users\James>
```

[image]

```
for lyr in lyrlist:
        lyr.visible = False
        #if lyr.name in layers and lyr.name <> layer:
        #   lyr.visible = False
        if lyr.name == "citylyr":
            lyr.visible = True
        if lyr.name == "boundlyr":
            lyr.visible = True
        if lyr.name == name:
            lyr.visible = True
            layerOn = lyr.name

            for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
                if elm.name == 'TestName':
                    elm.text = lyr.name
                if elm.name == 'TestName2':
                    elm.text = 'Example Map Title Name'
                else:
                    elm.text = ""

    if layerOn:
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(mxd,r"{}\{}.gif".format(GIFPath,layerOn))
```

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  Cloning of text elements only became available in ArcPy a few versions back.  Please always include errors as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be in your `else:` - it's trying to set your `elm.text` even if there isn't an option for text.  You don't need to set `elm.text` if there's no text to change/remove in that element.

I'd also move the `for elm...` loop in with the export just to keep things tidier (and easier to read).

```
elements = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT")
for layer in layers:
    layerOn = ""
    for lyr in lyrlist:
            lyr.visible = False
            #if lyr.name in layers and lyr.name <> layer:
            #   lyr.visible = False
            if lyr.name == "citylyr":
                lyr.visible = True
            if lyr.name == "boundlyr":
                lyr.visible = True
            if lyr.name == name:
                lyr.visible = True
                layerOn = lyr.name

    if layerOn:
        for elm in elements:
            if elm.name == 'TestName':
                elm.text = layerOn
            if elm.name == 'TestName2':
                elm.text = 'Example Map Title Name'
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToGIF(mxd,r"{}\{}.gif".format(GIFPath,layerOn))
```

*I have re-added a couple of code lines from your [original question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/183508/64785) so that the added `elements...` line is added in context.*